# While downloading, contents are taking more time in server as compared to my local host(chrome)

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I am facing  performance issues with a dynamic .aspx web page.When I checked in the google developer tools I have seen this stats as TTFB as "2.6s" and Content Download as "13.51s" for "1.4MB" size and this is taking almost 15 seconds to load my page.I am facing this problem only in my rack space server,In my local machine this content Download is  "1.5s".Could Anyone please explain Why is the huge difference from my local host to server.And what is actually happening in this content downloading and how to improve performance of my page.Any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Network delay most probably

Comment: Make a `traceroute` from your server and check all the delays.

Comment: "I am facing this problem only in my rack space server" -> is delay experienced if open page in a browser in your server machine? Is your local machine connected to Rackspace via VPN or your machine is also a Rackspace machine?

Comment: traceroute I will explore about that.

Comment: My  local machine connected to Rackspace via Remote Desktop connection and I have deployed my local code in that server.After closing that connection to my server. I came back to my application( ex:testapp.com/mytestpage.aspx).

Comment: 3 seconds of latency is very much, even your Rackspace machine is not **physically** in the same network. You say you're using RDP, if it'd be a network issue to server you would have a very slow RDP experience too. Can you show us what's not shown in the left of image too?

Comment: @Andre Figueiredo I have added one more image.I can provide  any further info in case needed.